# Macbook Air 2013 causing Wifi Drop

Tags: network, wifi

Odd problem. If I use my iPhone or my wife's iPhone, my LG TV, and the Apple TV in my kids bedroom, the wifi router works as expected. The moment that I start to use a Macbook Air 2013 (Mojave 10.14.4 (18E226)) on the same network, the wifi drops, and stops working on **all** devices.

I pinged www.google.com and this is what I get:

```
64 bytes from 172.217.29.4: icmp_seq=89 ttl=56 time=40.477 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.4: icmp_seq=90 ttl=56 time=61.264 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.4: icmp_seq=91 ttl=56 time=33.568 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.4: icmp_seq=92 ttl=56 time=34.179 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.4: icmp_seq=93 ttl=56 time=35.228 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 94
Request timeout for icmp_seq 95
Request timeout for icmp_seq 96
Request timeout for icmp_seq 97
```

Every thing working and suddenly bam, timeout, timeout, the only options that I have:

1. Turn off wifi and turn on again, use a few moments and the same thing happens.
2. Turn off the router and turn on again, I gain a few moments of happiness.

Solutions that I've tried:

1. Remove the files com.apple.airport.preferences.plist, com.apple.network.eapolclient.configuration.plist, NetworkInterfaces.plist, preferences.plist, restarted the device. DID NOT WORK
2. Change the Location on the Network properties on General/Network. DID NOT WORK
3. Add the google DNS on the WIFI network. DID NOT WORK.
4. Remove the option from the router WMM. DID NOT WORK.
5. If I turn off the router I have like 20min until the connection drops, then every device on the house hangs, the TV, the phones.
   6.Tried sudo ifconfig awdl0 down, DID NOT WORK.
6. Changed the router channel to 11. **WAITING**

The last responses from ping:

```
64 bytes from 172.217.30.100: icmp_seq=499 ttl=56 time=34.396 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.30.100: icmp_seq=500 ttl=56 time=34.338 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 501
Request timeout for icmp_seq 502
Request timeout for icmp_seq 503
Request timeout for icmp_seq 504
Request timeout for icmp_seq 505
Request timeout for icmp_seq 506
Request timeout for icmp_seq 507
Request timeout for icmp_seq 508
Request timeout for icmp_seq 509
Request timeout for icmp_seq 510
Request timeout for icmp_seq 511
Request timeout for icmp_seq 512
Request timeout for icmp_seq 513
Request timeout for icmp_seq 514
Request timeout for icmp_seq 515
Request timeout for icmp_seq 516
```

I hope to find a solution because since it's an Air model I don't want to buy an adapter and get back to ethernet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Why not have the Air repaired or replaced if it’s causing you interference?

I don’t think we’ll be able to review all the extensive work you’ve done without being in the room with you so unless you think you have marked something as DID NOT WORK when you really didn’t complete those steps, I think this is pretty clearly that you need a router that can accommodate interference from a device that’s failing or you need to remove the failed device from the environment that can’t tolerate it.

Also, a proper wireless survey might find out the details, but the costs and experience are high to do a proper analysis of the actual radio transmissions with WireShark or actually measuring the RFI.